# Receiving two different possible type objects in the body of a .NET POST API request

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net

I have these two classes:

```
public class FieldStructure
    {
        public FieldStructure(string name, string type)
        {
                Name = name;
                Type = type;
                NameAsProperty = name.ToLower().Replace(" ", "_");
            
        }

        public FieldStructure() { }

        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string NameAsProperty { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Type { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    }

    public class FieldStructureRelation : FieldStructure
    {
        public FieldStructureRelation(FieldStructure fieldStructure, string appRelationId, string appRelationName) 
            : base(fieldStructure.Name, fieldStructure.Type)
        {
            this.AppRelationName = appRelationName;
            this.AppRelationId = appRelationId;
        }

        public FieldStructureRelation() { }

        public string AppRelationId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string AppRelationName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

And this controller:

```
[HttpPost("{workspaceId}/add")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateApp([FromBody] AppDTOCreate request, string workspaceId)
        {
            if (request == null) { return BadRequest(); }
             
            //App app = new App() { AppName = request.AppName, Fields = request.Fields};
            //await _appServices.InsertApp(app, workspaceId);
            return Created("Created", true);
        }
```

With this being the object that I'm supposed to receive:

```
public class AppDTOCreate
    {
        public string AppName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public List<FieldStructure> Fields { get; set; } = new List<FieldStructure>();
    }
```

So, basically, all I want is to be able to receive a JSON request that contains an `AppDTOCreate` with a list of both `FieldStructures` and `FieldStructureRelations`. I thought it would be as easy as to do what I've already done, but whenever I receive the request, all my code sees are `FieldStructures`, whenever I get to a `FieldStructureRelation`, it erases the `AppRelationName` and `AppRelationId` fields, so it remains as a `FieldStructure`.

This is the JSON I'm using as an example:

```json
{
    "AppName":"Prueba",
    "Fields": [
        {
            "Name": "Name",
            "Type": "text"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Active",
            "Type": "boolean"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Total Sales",
            "Type": "decimal"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Cliente",
            "Type": "itemRelation",
            "AppRelationId": "appIdxxxxxx",
            "AppRelationName": "AppNameABC"
        }
    ]
}
```

If anyone can help me figuring out what's wrong here I'd very much appreciate it!

Comment: See following and the paragraph above : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0#iresult-type  The body is IActionResult and the types are IResult.

Comment: It's asp.net core?

Comment: @vernou yes it is

Comment: Why not define your `Fields` property in `AppDtoCreate` as `List<FieldStructureRelation>` instead of `List<FieldStructure>`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this converter

```
    AppDTOCreate data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppDTOCreate>(json);
    
   //test
    data.Fields[2].GetType().ToString(); // "FieldStructure"
    data.Fields[3].GetType().ToString(); // "FieldStructureRelation"

public class DataPropertyConverter : JsonConverter<List<FieldStructure>>
{
    public override List<FieldStructure> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<FieldStructure> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jArray = JArray.Load(reader);
        
        return jArray.Select(jObj=> (FieldStructure) jObj.ToObject(
                              Type.GetType((string)jObj["Type"] == "itemRelation"
                              ? nameof(FieldStructureRelation)
                              : nameof(FieldStructure))))
                              .ToList();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<FieldStructure> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

fix the class

```
public class AppDTOCreate
{
    public string AppName { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DataPropertyConverter))]
    public List<FieldStructure> Fields { get; set; }
}
```